# CSS transform: rotate

Tags: css, image, rotation, transform

```css
/* Title image */

.title-image {
  width: 60%;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class"col-lg-67">
        <img class"title-image" src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">

      </div>
```

I am doing the Dr. Angela Yu web development course from Udemy.

I am having trouble with the CSS  transform: rotate(25deg);

I don't understand why it isn't working. I did it the same way she has.

This is to rotate an image.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what isn't working for you? Maybe share a code snippet to give an overview of the problem.

Comment: Do you have any other transforms on that element?

Comment: I don't have any other transform elements. Is that enough snippet. I can add the whole code if needed.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your CSS class isn't being applied to HTML. You've missed an `=` after class in HTML.

```html
<div class"col-lg-67">
        <img class="title-image" src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">

      </div>
```